# How to set up JetBrains IDE to run Stencil e2e tests?

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, stenciljs

We're developing a design system with Stencil. We are now writing e2e tests as described in [Stencil docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/end-to-end-testing).

There is [shared VS Code config](https://stenciljs.com/docs/testing-overview#running-and-debugging-tests-in-vs-code) which allows to run the tests with Visual Studio Code, but we're using JetBrains IDEs (IntelliJ IDEA and WebStorm) and it is not obvious how to set up tests to run them with IDE interface.

Did anyone managed to set up them in JetBrains IDEs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Node.js](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.3/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html) run configuration with similar setup: specify the project root folder as a **Working directory**, `path/to/node_modules/.bin/stencil` as **JavaScript file**, add `test --e2e $FilePath$` to **Application parameters**